# How to keep tooltip from closing on mouse-down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using jquery UI tooltip with a div element which upon selection changes its background image. The selection is also done via jquery UI. When hovering over the element the tooltip shows as expected, but when selecting the element the tooltip will close on mouse down and re-open on mouse-up, leading to an unwanted flicker. How can I avoid that flicker? I prefer not to use a delay upon closing the tooltip, since that leads to other unwanted effects.

Code (somewhat simplified):

```
$('#myDiv').tooltip({
        tooltipClass: 'myTooltip',
        track: true,
        show: null,
        hide: null,
        position: { my: "left+15 top+25", at: "right bottom" }

 });


setUpSelectable = function (id, filterType, selVar, funCB) {
    $(id).selectable({
        filter: filterType,
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            // Select new element
            if (selVar.val == null || selVar.val.attr('id') !== $(ui.selected).attr('id'))
                selVar.val = $(ui.selected);
            else { // toggle already set element.
                selVar.val.removeClass("ui-selected");
                selVar.val = null;
            }
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            // Remove all the other selected elements -> no multi select
            if (selVar.val != null)
                selVar.val.siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");

            // callback
            (funCB());
        }
    });
};
```

css:

```
 .myTooltip { 
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
width: 80px;
height: 20px;
box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
border-radius: 6px;
text-align:center;
color: #9F9270;
background: none repeat 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
line-height: 20px;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size: 12px;    
}
```

Comment: put your code here. jQuery tooltip has no such flicker problem as you say. So, you must have set up this tooltip in incorrect way.

Comment: I added the basic code in an edit above.

Comment: It would be great if you could share a jsfiddle.

Comment: Maybe you could avoid the flicker by unbind the tooltip from focus events. $('#myDiv').tooltip().off("focusin focusout");

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to open up your initial tooltip yourself programmatically:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-open

```
$('.yourdiv').on('mousedown',function(){
   $('.yourtooltip').tooltip('open');
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but sadly it doesn't fix the issue.